# Excel Wildcard not working on same data table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wildcard, countif

I use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!N2:N5001, ">"&J1, Sheet2!N2:N5001, "<"&K1,Sheet2!P2:P5001,"*")
```

and it returns a value, when I parse a different date range with this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!N2:N5001, ">"&J12, Sheet2!N2:N5001, "<"&K12,Sheet2!P2:P5001,"*")
```

it returns no values, when looking at the data source, there are values which it should return, I've checked that the data source in column P is all text values, why is the wildcard not working?

Comment: Try changing the `"*"` to `"<>"`. I'm assuming that all you want is a non-blank cell.

Comment: Btw, if you are filling or copying that formula down then those rows should (at a minimum) be row absolute like `Sheet2!N$2:N$5001`

Comment: Still nothing, Its strange, The J and K cells are my date range, I have every month from January through May working fine, but for June it won't output, anything.

Comment: Assuming that you have not manually changed the cell alignment, are the other months right-aligned and June dates left-aligned?

Comment: If it works for other months, then the fault is not with the formula but the data.

Comment: All the data is in the same column, I've forced all the column's data to text, so the formula for the others is parsing the same exact data, just within different date ranges, I've tried to input data into empty cells as just text but still its not counting it, very strange.

Comment: We are not going to be able to help, our crystal balls only work in hindsight.  The problem is with the data or the inputs, one or both are text and not dates.